# jQuery stopPropgation with future elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple table which has 2 tr's.

[image]

The last `td` on each `tr` is about to ( in the future) be inserted with a `button` :

```
var futureButton=$("<input  type='button' value='click' class='btn'  />");
```

So after the insertion :

`$(".myTable tr td:nth-child(5)").append(futureButton)`

It looks like this :

[image]

Those buttons should have `onClick` event (*they don't have inline onclick*)  , and so i attached the onclick to the body :

```
$("body").on('click',".btn",function (e){
  alert('button');
 
});
```

And here is my question :

Each `TR` has already have :

```
<tr onclick='alert("row");'> // I can't change it....it's an existing code.
```

So when I press the button I get **2 alerts** : `"row"` and then `"button"`

ButI want to get **only 1 alert** : "button"

However I can't stop propagation because it's too late when it reaches the "body"

nor - I cant change the Tr's "onclick"

What can I do  ?

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/icoxak/16/edit)**

## edit

Clarification. (sorry I **should** have emphasized that) :

Those buttons (which are the **question marks** in the animation) are tool tips which can be added to ANY HTML ELEMENT CONTAINER - so in compile time - I don't know where it gonna be :  ( and that's why I binded their onclick to the "body")

And you can see that when i press on the question mark - the whole "`tr`" thinks I pressed on it and shows data ( and I **don't** want it to show data).

[image]

So I **dont** know where the Js plugin will insert this button / question mark...

Comment: I think all the answers posted here pretty much cover it all, but just dropping by to say one hell of a question format, kudos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would *hot patch* the existing `inline click handlers` beforehand, like so:

```
$( ".myTable tr" ).each(function( _, tr ) {
  var inlineClick = tr.onclick;

  $( tr ).on('click', function( event ) {
    if( !$(event.target).hasClass( 'btn' ) ) {
      inlineClick.call( event.target );
    }
  });

  tr.onclick = null;
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/icoxak/26/edit

---

Here, we cache the current *function reference* and add our own code. In that code, I just check whether or not the *click target* has a `class` of `btn`. This test could be more precise of course.

However, if we don't have a match, we execute the original *click handler*, otherwise we do nothing at all.

We also can repeat this code if necessary (if for instance, new rows get inserted), but we have to make sure that our own *click handlers* get cleared before so we don't create multiple instances.

Comment: @RoyiNamir it shouldn't make a difference anyway. If we *duck punch* the existing inline click handlers bound to the `tr elements`, we can punch it as hard and as long as we need to until it works the way we want.

Comment: elegant solution. I also changed your code to `$("body").on('click',".btn",function (e)..`  so it will suite my needs and it works. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can be more specific with the selector where you are attaching the `click` event:

```
$(".myTable tr td").on('click', ".btn", function (e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('button');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach `.on()` to the `td`, and use `stopPropagation()` to prevent bubbling and triggering the inline click hander on the `tr`:

```
$('td').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('button'); 
});
```

#### [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/icoxak/22/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this too:

http://jsbin.com/icoxak/21/edit

```
$('tr[onclick]').each(function(){
  this._onclick = this.onclick;
  this.removeAttribute('onclick');
});

$("body").on('click',".myTable tr",function (e){
  if(!$(e.target).hasClass('btn'))
       this._onclick.apply(this,arguments);
});
```

Comment: You realize that my question is a simplification of much complex working code. and I can't just remove the Tr's onclick....